# When is it Safe to Return Span<T> Initialized from Stack-Allocated Variable / Buffer?

Tags: .net, memory, stack, c#-7.3

Are the following 2 examples of returning `Span<byte>` (and `Span<T>` more generally) safe in a sense that when the method returns, the memory location to which the returned instance of `Span<T>` points still contains meaningful data:

```
  static class Example {

    public static void Main() {
      var n = 0x0102030405060708U;
      var n_bytes_as_span_of_byte = n.ToBytesExtension();
      var n2 = 0x8899aabbccddeeffU; // <- will this "overwrite" span-contents above?
      //Do something with both n2 and n_bytes_as_span_of_byte...

      //Do something with StackAllocExtensions
    }


    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
   public static unsafe Span<byte> ToBytesExtension(
      this ulong num // <- Will making it 'ref' make any difference: 'this ref ulong num'?
    ) => new Span<byte>( // <- Will returning it by 'ref' make any difference: ... => ref ...?
      Unsafe.AsPointer(ref num) // <- What if we use '&num' instead of 'Unsafe.AsPointer(ref num)'
      , sizeof(ulong));


      [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Span<byte> StackAllocExtensionThatDoesNotCompile(ulong someArg) {
      Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[16];
      //Do something with span and someArg...

      return span; // <- Does not work: Cannot use local 'span' in this context because it may expose referenced variables outside of their declaration scope.
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static unsafe Span<byte> StackAllocExtensionThatCompiles(ulong someArg) {
      var byte_pointer = stackalloc byte[16];
      //Do something with span and someArg...

      return new Span<byte>(byte_pointer, 16); // <- But isn't this the same as above? I.e. "exposes referenced variables outside of their declaration scope"?
    }

  }
```

Also:

- How does using `ref return` and `ref` parameters affect this (if at all)?
- Does inlining make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe because the memory allocated using `stackalloc` is no longer guaranteed to be available after the function exits.

In all cases where this compiles you have used unsafe facilities to override the warnings. Using unsafe code you can do anything you want. For example you can return a pointer to an `int` on the stack (`int x = 0; return &x;`) which is just as unsafe.

It cannot be any other way because there is no way the language or runtime could track lifetimes through these unsafe facilities. Even if it could track it it would destroy the performance benefits of `stackalloc`. `stackalloc` memory is fast because it is known to be released on function exit.